# How to change the attribute of an element in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Is it possible to change the attribute of an HTML element with code in Angular? I have a button that I want it to change the type attribute of an input from password to text. This is what came to mind at first:

Template:

```
<input name="password" type="password" />

<button click="showPassword()">eye</button>
```

Component:

```
 showPassword() : void
 {
      //how do I change the password input to text input. Is there a better way to do this?
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input name="password" [type]="password" />
```

In ts file

```
 public password='password';
 showPassword() : void
 {
      this.password=(this.password=='password')?'text':'password';
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML,

```
<input name="password" [type]='password' />

<button click="showPassword()">eye</button>
```

In your TS,

```
export class ClassName {
     password: String = 'password';
     showPassword() : void{
       this.password = (this.password=='password')?'text':'password';
     }
}
```